# Search engine Crawling in Angular Apps on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, web-crawler, headless-browser

I'm using Angular js for my web front end, and ASP.NET as my back end.

Can someone point me to a headless browser I can easily use to render content on the server side for web crawlers.

I am looking at [Awesomium.NET](http://www.awesomium.com/) and [WebKit.NET](https://github.com/webkitdotnet/webkitdotnet) and both seems like an ovekill (to me. corect me if I'm wrong.)

Can anyone recommend me something more lightweight and targets to solve crawling issues in SPA type web apps ?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) is the way to go. Among other things, you'll need to create a JS script so you can render your pages as pure HTML before returning them to the web crawlers. More info on that [here](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html).